# What are the components (or radicals) that comprise the character '兼'?

Tags: glyph-origin, character-components

Without the knowledge of a character's components or radicals, I find some difficulty recalling the meaning or pronunciation of that character. I have looked at [this poster](https://store.mandarinposter.com/simplified-chinese-radicals-list-free-printable-reference) containing radicals here, but cannot place which radicals comprise it. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is just *components*. Characters aren't comprised of *radicals* (部首; *section header*). Radicals are just modern stroke-shapes used as indexing tools to mark the *heading* (首) of *dictionary sections* (部), equivalent to the first letter of an English word when you look it up in a dictionary ("A", "B", "C", etc.), and may not be related to the character at all.

Since a character isn't indexed under more than one radical in a dictionary, we also don't speak of characters having multiple radicals, just like English words don't have more than one first letter.

---

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 兼] | 11 [曾侯竹簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_of_Marquis_Yi_of_Zeng#Other_contents) |
| [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [image: 兼] | [秝部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=110) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 兼] | 衡方碑 |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 兼] |  |

「兼」 is a picture of a [*hand* 「又」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20) simultaneously grasping *two* [*cereal plants* 「禾](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=281)禾」, indicating the meaning *simultaneously*, *concurrently*.

Be wary of the shape changes in 「兼」 over the course of history: 「又」 is still present in the middle of 「兼」 and now looks like 「⋺」, while the top of 「禾禾」 has been reduced to 「䒑」.

Answer (score 0):

the main radical is 八, and the components are 䒑、⺕、八、丨 as per pleco.

For these types of questions often a dictionary is still the best choice.  I am sure there are probably online ones as well if you prefer to pleco.